# Avoid adding duplicate entries in Set

Tags: java, hashset

I am doing this

1)Check if entry exists in my HashSet 
2) If yes then skip
3) If no then add

Below is the code. My output shows duplicate entries for Employee object and not for integer types. How can I correct the code below?

```
import java.util.*;

public class SetTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashSet <Employee> e1=new HashSet<Employee>();

        e1.add(new Employee(1,"bob"));
        e1.add(new Employee(2,"eric"));

        if(!e1.contains(new Employee(1,"bob")))
        {
            e1.add(new Employee(1,"bob"));
        }

        for(Employee e:e1) {
            System.out.println(e.getId()+" "+e.getName());
        }

        HashSet e2=new HashSet();
        e2.add(1);
        e2.add(2);
        e2.add(1);

        System.out.println(e2);



    }

}
class Employee{
    int id;
    String name;

    Employee(int id,String name) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Implement `equals` and `hashCode`. Next!

Comment: For a hashed collection you need to implement equals()/hashCode() appropriately for Employee, and then a HashSet will guarantee you don't have any duplicates...

Comment: Also: you don't need to check if the set contains the element first. Just call `add`, and if the element already exists in the set, it won't be added again.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

`if(!e1.contains(new Employee(1,"aravind")))`

You've added an employee Object whose name field is "Aravind" to the set before, but in this line, the `new Employee` part creates a whole new *different* Employee, with the same name -- and since Objects in Java are by default compared by their addresses, these two Employees are different, even though their fields are identical.

I believe the solution you're looking for would be to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of your Employee class, so that it compares just ID and name, and then your HashSet would report that it's already got an employee with name Aravind and ID 1.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my code with hashCode and equals method and it fixed the issue.